# Using PIG with Hadoop, how do I regex match parts of text with an unknown number of groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm using Amazon's elastic map reduce.

I have log files that look something like this

```
   random text foo="1" more random text foo="2"
   more text notamatch="5" noise foo="1"
   blah blah blah foo="1" blah blah foo="3" blah blah foo="4" ...
```

How can I write a pig expression to pick out all the numbers in the 'foo' expressions?

I prefer tuples that look something like this:

```
(1,2)
(1)
(1,3,4)
```

I've tried the following:

```
TUPLES = foreach LINES generate FLATTEN(EXTRACT(line,'foo="([0-9]+)"'));
```

But this yields only the first match in each line:

```
(1)
(1)
(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `STRSPLIT`: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.0/piglatin_ref2.html#STRSPLIT

The regex to split on would be `[^0-9]+`  (i.e., not numbers)
This will effectively split on large portions of non-numbers, leaving only tokens of numerical digits.

Another option would be to write a Pig UDF.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Unfortunately, my example was misleading in that it didn't illustrate that I actually have other numeric expressions I don't want to match.  I've updated my example to be more illustrative.

Comment: Could you not use a Pig UDF to do this?

Answer (score 0):

REGEX_EXTRACT function may help you to get your desired output

REGEX_EXTRACT(input, 'foo=(.*)',2) AS input;